# not getting json data from view to template in django

Tags: json, django-templates, django-views

I want to  get json data from views and crate column chart. Below is the code
views.py

```
def PFTpercentChange(request):
    conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname="geodjango",host='localhost',user='postgres', password='postgres', port=5433)
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT COUNT(species) FROM pft_potential_pft")
    count_pot=cur.fetchall()
    cur.execute("select  count(*) from pft_existing_data_apft e inner join pft_potential_pft p on e.species= p.species ")
    count_actual=cur.fetchall()
    cur.executemany('UPDATE "PFTpercentchange" SET "PFTs_likely_to_change" = ( %s ) where id=1',count_pot)
    conn.commit()
    cur.executemany('UPDATE "PFTpercentchange" SET "PFTs_unchanged" = ( %s ) where id=1',count_actual)
    conn.commit()
    myData = {}
    myData['PFTs_likely_to_change'] = count_pot
    myData['PFTs_likely_to_remain_unchanged'] = count_actual
    json_string = json.dumps(myData)

    return JsonResponse(myData, safe=False)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^percent/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='PFTpercentchange.html'), name='PFTpercentChange')
```

PFTpercentchange.html

```
var data=$.getJSON('{% url "PFTpercentchange" %}');
```

Im getting error no reverse match. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Why you have write TemplateView in url? to call PFTpercentChange function you can make url like this,

```
url(r'^percent/$',PFTpercentChange.as_view(), name='PFTpercentChange').
```

Comment: Check your spell for 'PFTpercentChange' in urls you have given 'C' for 'Change' in name and in getJSON there is 'c' for 'PFTpercentchange' so it couldn't find reverse match.

Comment: I changed the name to 'PFTpercentChange' but its not working